# Rails 5: show link from navigation partial if user has particular role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, partial-views, partial

I my app I need to show/hide links to sections according to user role.

In *models/roles.rb* I have:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
  enum dashboard: { denied: 0, viewer: 1, editer: 2, creater: 3, deleter: 4}, _suffix: true
```

In *controllers/dashboards_controller.rb* I have:

```
def dashboard_1
@roles = current_user.roles
  if @roles.any? { |role| role.creater_dashboard? || role.deleter_dashboard? }
    @creater_deleter = true
  elsif @roles.any? { |role| role.viewer_dashboard? }
    @viewer = true
  else
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

In *layouts/application.html.erb* I have this:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
     <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
```

and in partial *layouts/_navigation.html.erb* I have this:

```
<li class="<%= is_active_controller('dashboards') %>">
   <%= link_to dashboard_path do %>
   <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.dashboard">Dashboard</span>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
 </li>

<li class="<%= is_active_controller('campaigns') %>">
   <%= link_to campaigns_path do %>
   <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.campaigns">Campaigns</span>
   <% end %>
 </li>
... #other links to different parts of app
```

**How to show "dashboard" link in partial if user is @creator_deleter?** Note: However I need to show "campaigns" link to all users. As I have found out I might be start using AJAX from this point... Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to pass the `@creator_deleter` instance variable into the partial as a local.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation', locals: { creator_deleter: @creator_deleter } %>
```

Then inside your partial you can check for it

```
<li class="<%= is_active_controller('dashboards') %>">
<% if creator_deleter %>
  <%= link_to dashboard_path do %>
    <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.dashboard">Dashboard</span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working as in _layouts/_navigation.html.erb_ gives this error: _undefined local variable or method `creator_deleter'_ It seems that instance variable is not passed to partial this way.